# Why is Gradle Plugin not collecting build scan in Jenkins file

Tags: gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile based pipeline which does a build using gradle, which then produces build scan that goes in console output. I found a Jenkins plugin (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin) that scans the console and nicely displays all build scan links.

When I integrated in my Jenkinsfile based pipeline it does not work.

Here the Jenkins file:

```
node {
    // This displays colors using the 'xterm' ansi color map.

    try {
        wrap([$class: 'BuildScanBuildWrapper']) {
            stage "Create build output"
            println "Doing gradle build"
            sh "cd projects/ospackage-plugin/ && ./gradlew -I ./init.gradle tasks"
        }

    }
    catch (err) {
        println "FAILURE: ${err}"
        throw err
    }

}
```

Comment: Found out this is not supported for the pipline style of jobs.
{code}
src/main/java/hudson/plugins/gradle/GradleConsoleLogFilter.java


        if (build instanceof FreeStyleBuild) {
{code}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with the plugin version 1.33, it is now possible to collect build scan links from pipeline Jobs: https://plugins.jenkins.io/gradle#GradlePlugin-CapturingbuildscansfromJenkinsPipeline

Add `findBuildScans()` to the end of your pipeline script:

```
node {
    ...
}

findBuildScans()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, planning to use it soon.